# Using a dynamic JS Variable in an HTML link

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic Amazon link in which I am trying to reuse a dynamic javascript variable that is used elsewhere (previous to this link) in the code for the key words ...

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music&field-keywords="'+val.sources[0].title+'>
```

OR

```
<script>
    $.each(track, function(index, val) {
    trackHtml  += '<a href="https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music&field-keywords='+val.sources[0].title+'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-bottom:3px"></i><br> Buy at Amazon</a>';});
</script>
```

Can this be done? and if so, the above syntax is not working. Do I have to place entirely in JS and do a html output?

This is the code that precedes my explanation above - so I am calling and creating the variable into a JSON file"

```
sources: [{
   track_id: '{$row['id']}',
   title: \"{$row['title']}\",
   artist: '{$row['artist']}',
   src: \"{$row['source_url']}\",
   poster: \"{$row['source_poster']}\",
   type: 'audio/mp3'
}],";
```

Comment: As far as i know, that's not possible. You could bind a click event to this anchor tag and replace the URL in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with the string first and then you can apply it to the HTML element:

```js
// Get a reference to the link
var link = document.getElementById("theLink");

// Faking the data for our purposes
var val = {};
val.sources = [{
  title:"TEST"
}];

// Append to the href
link.href += val.sources[0].title;

// Test
console.log(link.href);
```

```html
<a id="theLink" href="https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music&field-keywords=">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music" onclick="location.href=this.href+'&keywords='+val.sources[0].title;return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: Looks efficient and great BUT the js portion is not binding to the end of the search - on click only shows the base link?: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music

Comment: can you show how are you passing the param? It works if I pass a dummy string